# apt autoremove asking to remove linux image generic, is it safe?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

when I ran it recently it showed me this

```
~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-46 linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-46-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-46-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 583 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

should I not trust autoremove anymore? I usually run apt autoremove and clean cause it helps avoiding breaking packages during apt upgrade

Comment: It's fine to remove them; presumably it's because you have updated to the latest version (`uname -a`).  If you need it back, you can always install it back yourself.  I'm not sure if `autoremove` will minimize the chance of breaking packages...what it will do is just keep your disk clean by removing software that is no longer needed.

Comment: From your question. I usually run apt autoremove and clean cause it helps avoiding breaking packages during apt upgrade. Do you have a place I can find this info by a reliable source, I do not believe it to be true.

Comment: qbittorent would break on install every time I remove and installed it. autoremove and clean fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `autoremove` command removes one specific older kernel version that is not anymore in use. Nowadays, `autoremove` also will remove older kernels, except the previous kernel and the current one. Thus, you always keep the option to boot to the previous kernel. It therefore is a safe way to automatically clean up older kernels.

In general, `autoremove` removes packages that once were automatically installed, i.e., as a dependency of another package, but which currently are not anymore required by any other package, thus only take up disk space.

Comment: this was the correct answer. it was an older version. running autoremove did not brick my pc.